# Import CSV file with tab delimited using PHPExcel lib

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, yii2-advanced-app, phpexcelreader

I'm trying to import CSV file using PHPExcel lib. My CSV file has `\t` or **tab** as delimiter.

So when I'm trying to printout the result in my screen, every **comma** seen as new cell, just like this
[image]

But actually I need to export data in one line for each row and separated by quotation-sign (**"**) for each **tab** delimiter, just like this one
[image]

This is my code in **Controller** for reading and write the data:

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcelDetail->getActiveSheet();
        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                echo '<pre>';
                echo 'Row number: ' . $row->getRowIndex() . "\r\n";

                $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set     

                foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                    if (!is_null($cell)) {
                        echo 'Cell: ' . $cell->getCoordinate() . ' - ' . $cell->getValue() . "\r\n";
                    }
                }
        }
```

How can I read CSV file with `\t` separator, and set into one line for each row?

Comment: If all you need is reading that csv, `fgetcsv()` may be better.

Comment: @Maerlyn yah you're right. I've used it before, I used PHPExcel for csv because I also import an Excel file in one page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the code for **loading** the file that you need to think about.

Look at the methods available to the CSV Reader in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md).... you'll find that there is a [setDelimiter()](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md#pipe-or-tab-separated-value-files) method that allows you to say to use a `tab` rather than a `,`.

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV')
    ->setDelimiter("\t");
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($myFileName);
```

Comment: Yah you're right. It's exist in the docs, I've try and it's work. Thanks for the help.